# Random characters at beginning of decrypted data

Tags: .net, delphi, encryption, byte-order-mark, rijndaelmanaged

I am using a TADOQuery component in Delphi to read the contents of a column in a database which have been encrypted by a 3rd party .net application using RijndaelManaged algorithm. I have "sucessfully" decrypted the data back to its original XML format but there are random characters at the beginning of decrypted data.

```
?_????g???M.0"?>
<template xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" id="846aaa43-dc42-4bc7-98bd-bf643fd324cb" xmlns="http://web.net/schema">
    etc, etc, etc...
```

I have a feeling that this is the BOM but cannot figure a way of ignoring it during the reading / decrypting of the data.

I read the data like this:

```
tmpMemoryStream : TMemoryStream;
Result : TByteArray; (array of byte)

tmpMemoryStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
tmpMemoryStream.LoadFromStream( ADOQuery1.CreateBlobStream(ADOQuery1.FieldByName('Design'), bmRead) );

setLength(Result, tmpMemoryStream.Size);
tmpMemoryStream.Read(Result, 0, tmpMemoryStream.size);
```

The resulting `byte array` is then passed to a function that decrypts the data.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1**

Each encrypted file has the same header which looks like this:

```
A9 CD AA F5 AE 36 04 2F 04 2A A5 2F CE EF B0 83 C4 97 F7 CA 26 F7 28 ED F8 C3 26 F4 57 D5 CB EA 36 10 F9 9B A6 CE F2 67 6B 47 B9 16 6E A7 41 14 A2 CD 99 88 51 17 67 03 C0 C4 66 18 D6 2A 1F D2 DD 5F 24 83 14 87 96 35 90 B6 70 F1 E6 51 BD 7A AB 41 86 E8 4D F4 E0 B7 D4 0A 22 DA 26 BD 54 D4 DE D1 23 36 BE D8 C8 D9 EC D8 5B 0E 0B 1D BE D8 A3 BD B7 E4 37 40 EB 86 76 85 E5 F7 15 87 EB 47
```

The garbled first part of the decrypted data changes with each file, but as an example, looks like this:

```
3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 36 04 2F 04 2A 3F 2F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 26 3F 28 3F 3F 3F 26 3F 57 3F 3F 3F 36 10 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 67 6B 47 3F 16 6E 3F 41 14 3F 3F 3F 3F 51 17 67 03 3F 3F 66 18 3F 2A 1F 3F 3F 5F 24 3F 14 3F 3F 35 3F 3F 70 3F 3F 51 3F 7A 3F 41 3F 3F 4D 3F 3F 3F 3F 0A 22 3F 26 3F 54 3F 3F 3F 23 36 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 5B 0E 0B 1D 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 37 40 3F 3F 76 3F 3F 3F 15 3F 3F 47
```

**EDIT 2**
It was a problem with the `IV`... I was using the following code:

```
with myRijndaelManaged do
    begin
        BlockSize := 128;
        KeySize := 256;
        Key := myKey;
        IV := IV; <-- Should have been "myIV"
        Padding := PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        Mode := CipherMode.CBC;
    end;
```

Because it was in a `with` block, even though the `IV` variable wasn't set, it wasn't flagged as an error as it is a property of the `myRijndaelManaged` object. I changed `IV` to `myIV` which contained the correct byte array data.

Thanks for the pointer @bartonjs

Comment: First few bytes always the same? Perhaps encrypted content begins after that.

Comment: What are the hex values of that data?

Comment: Documentation does not mention it but the second parameter you pass to 'Read' is called "offset". I'd presume it is  used to determine the starting position for reading. If not, advance by using 'Position' or 'Seek'.

Comment: @KenWhite before or after decrypting?

Comment: After decrypting - whatever it is you're getting that is unexpected *after* decrypting, which would allow us to see if it's a BOM or known signature of some sort. The ?_??? stuff you've posted doesn't provide any useful information.

Comment: @KenWhite - it changes with each data source. 3F 3F 19 52 5B 70 3F 2D 3F 3F 0A 3F 45 26 54 3F 2E 30 22 3F 3E 0D 0A

Comment: @KenWhite - Each encrypted file seems to have this header - 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 36 04 2F 04 2A 3F 2F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 26 3F 28 3F 3F 3F 26 3F 57 3F 3F 3F 36 10 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 67 6B 47 3F 16 6E 3F 41 14 3F 3F 3F 3F 51 17 67 03 3F 3F 66 18 3F 2A 1F 3F 3F 5F 24 3F 14 3F 3F 35 3F 3F 70 3F 3F 51 3F 7A 3F 41 3F 3F 4D 3F 3F 3F 3F 0A 22 3F 26 3F 54 3F 3F 3F 23 36 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 5B 0E 0B 1D 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 37 40 3F 3F 76 3F 3F 3F 15 3F 3F 47

Comment: @kenWhite - Just realised that was from a ascii encoded byte array, this is the original stream header - A9 CD AA F5 AE 36 04 2F 04 2A A5 2F CE EF B0 83 C4 97 F7 CA 26 F7 28 ED F8 C3 26 F4 57 D5 CB EA 36 10 F9 9B A6 CE F2 67 6B 47 B9 16 6E A7 41 14 A2 CD 99 88 51 17 67 03 C0 C4 66 18 D6 2A 1F D2 DD 5F 24 83 14 87 96 35 90 B6 70 F1 E6 51 BD 7A AB 41 86 E8 4D F4 E0 B7 D4 0A 22 DA 26 BD 54 D4 DE D1 23 36 BE D8 C8 D9 EC D8 5B 0E 0B 1D BE D8 A3 BD B7 E4 37 40 EB 86 76 85 E5 F7 15 87 EB 47

Comment: For goodness sake! Don't bury it in the comments - [edit] your question and put it there, where it can be formatted and read easily. This is information that is highly relevant to your question, and it belongs there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks a rather lot like you are not setting the IV value during decryption, leading to the first 16 bytes having plaintext recovery problems.

For full recovery you need the cipher text, key, and original IV (for modes other than ECB).